# Check the following inequalities with the Chebyshev inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X \sim Poi(\lambda).$ Use the Chebyshev inequality to check the next inequalities:

- $\mathbb{P}[X\leq{\frac{\lambda}{2}}] $   $\leq{\frac{4}{\lambda}}.$
- $\mathbb{P}[X\geq{\frac{2}{\lambda}}] $  $\leq{\frac{1}{\lambda}}.$

I assumed that $X$ is non-negative, then as $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{V}ar(X) = \lambda$, I got $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ and substituted in Chebyshev inequality but my inequalities weren't met. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any random variable $X$ with $\operatorname{E}[X^2]<\infty $ and $c< \operatorname{E}[X]$ we have that

$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr [X\leqslant c]&=\Pr [-X\geqslant -c]\\
&=\Pr [\operatorname{E}[X] -X\geqslant \operatorname{E}[X] -c]\\
&\leqslant \Pr [|X-\operatorname{E}[X]|\geqslant \operatorname{E}[X] -c]\\
&\leqslant \frac{\operatorname{Var[X]}}{(\operatorname{E}[X] -c)^2}
\end{align*}
$$

Then if $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda )$ and $c=\lambda /2$ we find that $\Pr [X\leqslant \lambda /2]\leqslant 4/\lambda $, as desired. For the second case it seems that there is a typo, it probably must be $\Pr [X\geqslant 2\lambda ]\leqslant 1/\lambda $ instead of the given inequality (by example taking $\lambda =2$ we can see that the given inequality doesn't hold as $\Pr [X\geqslant 1]>3/4$).